# Edittexts dont hide the Imageview

Tags: java, android, keyboard

Why don't the `EditText`s hide the `imageview` on click.
The `imageview` in the xml has -> android:visibility="visible".
But if I click on an `EditText` it has to remove visibility.

*HideKeyboard.class:*

```
public class HideKeyboard {

    private boolean isKeyboardOpen = false;
    private EditText editText;

    public HideKeyboard(EditText editText) {
        editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                isKeyboardOpen = true;
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean getIsKeyboardOpen() {
        return isKeyboardOpen;
    }

}
```

*FragmentDemo.class*

```
private boolean isKeyboardOpen;

    private HideKeyboard hideKeyboard;
    private ImageView imageview;
    private boolean isKeyboardOpen;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.demo_fragment_, container, false);

    imageview= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);

    isKeyboardOpen = false;

    hideKeyboard= new HideKeyboard(edittext1);
    hideKeyboard= new HideKeyboard(edittext2);

    isKeyboardOpen = hideKeyboard.getIsKeyboardOpen();

    if (isKeyboardOpen) {
            ivLogo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    return view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

A few reasons.

1)You're only checking isKeyboardOpen in onCreate.  During onCreate you haven't clicked the edit text yet.  So it will never hide.  To make it disappear on any click, put it in the OnClickListener.

2)The way you've set it up, because you're overwriting the hideKeyboard object you would only check the 2nd edit text anyway.  If you want to check either, either change the HideKeyboard class to take multiple EditTexts, or use multiple HideKeyboard objects, save all of them, and check all of them.

Comment: thanks for answering. How can I check for multiple editexts? Do you have an example?

Comment: which onclicklistener you mean?

Comment: The one in your hide keyboard. If you want to do something whenever it's clicked, the code to do it has to be in there. Or you would need to poll checking if the keyboard is open, which isn't suggested

Comment: ok. I put "ivLogo.setVisibility(View.GONE);" in the onclicklistener. But it doesnt worked